# Washing machine / microwave motor - AC or DC

Tags: motor, dc-motor, generator

If I take an old washing machine motor and try to convert it into a generator would it work and if so would it generate AC or DC? Same question with a microwave motor. I know it uses permanent magnets but would it generate AC or DC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Washing machine motor: AC if it's one of those permanent magnet motors.
this path is popular amongh the DIY wind power community.

If it's an induction motor, AC but it only while connected to an AC supply.

Microwave motor, AC and some make high voltages a very low shaft RPMs due to the internal gearing.

Comment: Thanks. So the key is - if it is a permanent magnet motor it generates AC or else it pretty much does not act as a generator right?

Comment: if it's a brush commuated permanent magnet DC motor it will generate DC, if it's a series universal motor it will generate nothing, parallel universal DC, else AC.

Comment: Thank you. I assume in the case of an universal motor it is so because its all electromagnets and not permanent magnets.

Comment: series universal motors have no speed at which back emf exceeds the supply voltage, thus they can't be used unmodified as generators. convert them to parallel and they'll generate.